# Python scraping bs4 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, web-scraping

I hope you're well. Could you please tell why I can use my scraping script properly :)
It works with other website. I'm a beginner so I probably made a basic mistake

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import csv

links = []
for i in range(1):
    url = '*******/recettes/?page={}' + str(i)
    res  = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response)
    if response.ok:
        print('Page: ' + str(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        divs = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'field-item even')
        for div in divs:
            a = div.find('a')
            link = a['href']
            links.append('*******' + link)
        time.sleep(3)
print(len(links))

with open('urls3.txt', 'w') as file:
    for link in links:
        file.write(link + '\n')

"""

with open('urls3.txt', 'r') as inf:
  with open('recipes3.csv', 'w') as outf:
        outf.write('titre,image,url,\n')
        for row in inf:
            url = row.strip()
            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.ok:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
                titre = soup.find('h1')
                image = soup.find('img', {"id":"recipe-media-viewer-thumbnail-1"})['src']
                print(titre.text, image, url)
                outf.write(str(titre.text) + ',' + str(image) + ',' + str(url) +  '\n')
            time.sleep(1)    
"""
```

Could you please tell me why there is a mistake here :

```
<Response [200]>
Page: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex3.py", line 18, in <module>
    link = a['href']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It seems that under the `<div>` there aren't any `<a>` tag. But without the URL it's hard to tell.

Comment: `a = div.find('a')` here a is not found and `a` is thus `None`

Comment: links = []
for i in range(1):
    url = 'https://www.regal.fr/recettes/?page={}' + str(i)
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response)
    if response.ok:
        print('Page: ' + str(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        divs = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'field-item even')
        for div in divs:
            a = div.find('a')
            link = a['href']
            links.append('https://www.regal.fr/' + link)
        time.sleep(3)
print(len(links))

Comment: for the link :) 
How I can display other results even if there is a lack of some a?

Comment: Because for instance in other scripts it works but after showing me 5-6 results I've this again:

Cake au chorizo https://assets.afcdn.com/recipe/20141108/40774_w1024h768c1cx2296cy1423.jpg 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex2.py", line 38, in <module>
    image = soup.find('img', {"id":"recipe-media-viewer-thumbnail-1"})['src']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, I post it here :) for anyone interested

```
try:    
    image = soup.find('img', {"id":"recipe-media-viewer-thumbnail-1"})['src']
except Exception as e:
    image = None
```